# Proxy a node server and websocket server under same subdomain with node-http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, subdomain, node-http-proxy

This is my proxy setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var vhost   = require('vhost');
var proxy   = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer();

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

// route api subdomain to port 2000
app.use(vhost('api.*.*', function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://localhost:2000'});
}));

// I need to get websocket requests to ws://api.example.com proxied port 4000
server.on('upgrade', function(req, socket, head) {
  // proxy.ws seems like the right way to go, but how do I get this under the vhost?
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});

// everything else goes to port 3000
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://localhost:3000'});
});

server.listen(80, function() {
  console.log('Proxy listening on port 80.');
});
```

Do I need to dive into the `req, res` objects inside the vhost handler to route the socket request? What is the right approach?

#### Update

Not pretty, but I'm going to give this a try.

```
server.on('upgrade', function(req, socket, head) {
  var host = req.headers.host;
  var parts = host.split('.');
  if (parts.length === 3 && parts[0] === 'api') {
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head, {target: {target: 'http://localhost:2000'});
  }
});
```

Hopeful for a more elegant vhost-like solution.

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)` Have you gotten something similar to that?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz No, I have a server running on port 2000 and 3000. They work great. I just can't figure out the websocket part.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz I got it figured out in case you're curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be as simple as this:

```
server.on('upgrade', vhost('api.*.*', function(req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
}));
```

`vhost` can be wrapped around the `upgrade` listener just like it can be used as middleware for http requests.